# How can I use my own data for calculations in Pine Script - Tradingview?

Tags: service-broker, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api, ohlc

there I am new to Pine Script and the Rest API.  The Rest API is for brokers. Have you implemented the Rest API.  I need to do this:

1. I am getting OHLC data from a different source.  I want to send this custom data to PINE script in Trading View and let it use my OHLC data to calculate all indicators.
2. Send this indicators values back to brokerage Rest API and I do trading or give custom signals from there

Who can help me with this?

Comment: I am referring to pine script